# Elasticsearch fielddata - should I use it?

Tags: elasticsearch

Given an index with documents that have a *brand* property, we need to create a term aggregation that is case insensitive.

**Index definition**

Please note that the use of **fielddata**

```
PUT demo_products
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_custom_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "brand": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer",
          "fielddata": true,
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Data**

```
POST demo_products/product
{
  "brand": "New York Jets"
}

POST demo_products/product
{
  "brand": "new york jets"
}

POST demo_products/product
{
  "brand": "Washington Redskins"
}
```

**Query**

```
GET demo_products/product/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "brand_facet": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "brand"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
"aggregations": {
    "brand_facet": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "new york jets",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "washington redskins",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

If we use `keyword` instead of `text` we end up the 2 buckets for New York Jets because of the differences in casing.

We're concerned about the performance implications by using fielddata. However if fielddata is disabled we get the dreaded *"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default."*

Any other tips to resolve this - or should we not be so concerned about fielddate?

Comment: How large are the machines hosting the ES instances (CPU, memory)? How many documents are we talking about? How many indices?

Comment: 300.000 docs divided in 28 indices, Elastic Cloud hosting (3 serveres, 4 GB at present)

Comment: Hm, why so many indices for that few documents?

Comment: Two options: either index everything in single case and then use `keyword` (and doc_values, not fielddata). Second option: make everything lowercase with `my_custom_analyzer` analyzer and use fielddata. Fielddata is regarded as a bad approach and it is in many cases. But if your nodes can handle the load (memory wise) and given the amount of fielddata memory being used, then why not using fielddata?

Comment: Fielddata is fine until you have memory pressure. If you do have memory issues, then you need to start looking for ways of improving the situation. And fielddata is usually the first thing that can be adjusted.

Comment: Reason for 28 indices: 1 index per market (us, uk, france, etc)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. #1- index in single case will prevent med from getting the "correct" casing "Washington Redskins". Instead I'll get "washington redskins" - this is not acceptable.

Comment: Another idea: Index a second field just for aggregations and in that one you index already lowercased values. Or just start using fielddata and monitor the performance. It might not be that bad you think it would.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with ES 5.2 (out today), you can use [normalizers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/analysis-normalizers.html) with `keyword` fields in order to (e.g.) lowercase the value.

The role of normalizers is a bit like analyzers for `text` fields, though what you can do with them is more restrained, but that would probably help with the issue you're facing.

You'd create the index like this:

```
PUT demo_products
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [ "lowercase" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "brand": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And your query would return this:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "brand_facet" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "new york jets",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "washington redskins",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Best of both worlds!

Comment: Can I specify it while inserting data? instead of making a separate `PUT` request.

Comment: @JayPatel no you can't, you need to create the index first

Answer (score 0):

You can lowercase the aggregation at query time if you use a script. It won't perform as well as a normalized keyword field, but is still quite fast in my experience. For example, your query would be:

```
GET demo_products/product/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "brand_facet": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc['brand'].value.toLowerCase()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```