# Getting the error Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default in CURL

Tags: java, curl, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, spring-data-elasticsearch

I tried this command:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bank/_search?pretty' -d ' { "size": 0, "aggs": { "group_by_state": { "terms": { "field": "state" } } } }'
```

When I'm executing it, then I always getting this error in elasticSearch:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set   fielddata=true on [state] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."
      }
    ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "bank",
        "node" : "B8uNFSm7TzO9KS3N72EFPg",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason" : "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [state] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."
    `enter code here`    }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status" : 400
}enter code here
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: If you search in SO you'll find  the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41868377/elasticsearch-fielddata-should-i-use-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your mapping and reindex

Use `keyword` type or `text` type with `fielddata: true`

Comment: i'm not getting that u r saying 'Use keyword type Or text with fielddata: true'

Comment: pls can u show this by any running example or any link?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41868377/elasticsearch-fielddata-should-i-use-it